# Error in installing tidyverse package in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, tidyverse

I am New to R programming. I am using R studio presently. I received the following error while installing the tidyverse package

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/mandava/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.3/tidyverse_1.1.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 41908 bytes (40 KB)
downloaded 40 KB

package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\mandava\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGw5Iny\downloaded_packages


My details :
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the error, the package is installed.